# List 'created by' in column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, survey

I know there is `surveylist.get_description` and `surveylist.get_itemCount`. I would like to know if there is a way to get created by fit in a column?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: if there is a surveylist.get_createdBy (doesnt seem to work that way).

Answer (score 1):

From syntax i guess you are using Javascriot CSOM.
Try this:

```
surveylist.get_author
```

Don't forget that you need to explicitly specify which properties you want to retrieve before you can get their values.

Comment: Doesnt work that way. I will post the script in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [List Author property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.author.aspx) is not exposed via SharePoint CSOM.

### How to retrieve List Author property via CSOM?

The idea is to retrieve [SPList.SchemaXml property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.schemaxml.aspx) and extract Author property

```
function getListAuthor(listTitle,OnSuccess,OnError) {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

    context.load(web);
    context.load(list,'SchemaXml');

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(sender,args){

        var schemaXml = $.parseXML(list.get_schemaXml());
        var authorId = parseInt($(schemaXml).find('List').attr('Author')); //SchemaXml contains Author ID only 

        var listAuthor = web.getUserById(authorId);
        context.load(listAuthor);
        context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess(listAuthor),OnError);

    },OnError);        
}



//Usage

getListAuthor('Discussions List',
function(author){
    console.log('List created by: ' + author.get_loginName())
},
function(sender,args){
    console.log('Error occured:' + args.get_message());
}
);
```